# Ligtning:recordEditForm onload , onSubmit ,onSucess action values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-recordeditform, aura-attribute

I have a doubt .During onLoad action ,are the record values the old and during the onSucess the record values are updated ? I want to send both the old and updated values of the record updated using Ligtning:recordEditForm to server side controller as parameters.How do I do that?

Comment: I have already answered that here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/328572/45062

Answer (score 0):

onLoad: the record's values is of course the old value.

onsuccess: you can retrieve the new values via id of the record.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow :

`onLoad` : Gets called when the component loads for the first time. So this will hold database values.

`onSubmit` : Gets called when you click the Submit button. If you have overridden it. This will hold all the new values if you have modified it from the form.

`onSuccess` : Gets called after the onSubmit is success and data has been persisted in the DB. After this again `onLoad` is called with the new database values.

For snippet on how to pass both data to server side check my answer [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/328572/45062)